# How do you relieve a cramp in an awkward part of your body?

Tags: injury, injury-prevention, cramps

I occasionally get random cramps in weird parts of my body. Parts that I can't seem to find a way to stretch. The only thing I can do is try to massage it or use my vibrating massage ball against it.

However, it only works for a short time (like a few seconds) before the cramp comes back again. For example, I am having a cramp in a place on my inner thigh which is really near my crotch after running(somewhere around here):

[image]

I've tried all of the above, but it still won't go away. Sometimes I also get random cramps in parts of my arm or neck that I can't stretch, so I just have to deal with the pain until it goes away.

Are there any other methods to relieving these types of cramps in awkward places? And is there any way of preventing them from happening in the first place since they can't be stretched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's (almost) always a stretch.  Stretching is most effective against cramp if you can get in early before the muscle is fully cramped, but be careful getting into position.

A [Cossack squat](https://powerliftingtechnique.com/cossack-squat/) as a stretch  works for where you've indicated (on the left), squatting on the other (right) leg with the cramped one out to the side.  One or both hands on the floor are a good idea if it's for stretching, especially with cramp.  You might reach the hand on the side you're stretching (left) down towards your ankle, and while your toes should normally point upwards in the Cossack squat, adjusting the angle can tweak the stretch.

A butterfly groin stretch is less helpful for cramp on one side, but if you've got it on both sides, the Cossack squat can make it worse in the leg that's taking the weight.  Getting down into the butterfly stretch is also more likely to aggravate cramp than going down to the Cossack squat.  Where the butterfly stretch might be of use is as a cool-down stretch after the run, in the hopes of preventing cramp.

Cramp varies between people.  I've always found good firm pressure (with a bit of movement) more helpful than a rubbing massage.  It's worth looking into prevention too. I also get a few seconds of pre-cramp when I can intervene, unless it comes on while I'm asleep.